# add animation to jquery validate plugin when removing error message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-animate

I am using the jquery validation plugin. I got it to animate for when It displays errors but I cant figure out how to add an animation for when the error is removed.

```
$('#newAccount').validate(
{
     rules: {},messages:{},
     errorPlacement: function(error, element)
     {
         error.insertAfter(element).hide().slideToggle(1000, 'easeOutBack');
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do some creative work to get back to your animated element. But I think the parameter you want to work with is *success* and you'll add the callback.

```
success: function(label) {
  label.next().is("--unique-css-class-name-").animate() 
}
```

You'll probably have to do some traversing to find your original animated element and work with it again.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, but from my reading of the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), the parameter passed to the `success` callback is the label itself, so you shouldn't need to traverse to find the label, you should just be able to animate the label element itself. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were inserting your own html after the label and then animating it.  If you're just animating the label than you are correct.  You could probably just to { label.slideToggle(); }

Comment: success can only modify the css and/or the class of the error label. It can not control the animation. also label is the current error so there isnt a need to traverse.

Comment: Have you tried loading the label into a jQuery object then manipulating it... 

$(label).slideToggle();